# Image loses quality when scaled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uipasteboard

I know that when scaling down an image you have to expect some loss of quality, but when I assign an image to a UIButton of size (75,75) it has great quality.

When I scale the image to size (75,75) for copy/paste using UIPasteboard it has really bad quality.

**Background:** My app is a keyboard extension, so I have buttons with assigned images and when they are clicked, I get the image from the button, scale it to be the right size, copy it to UIPasteboard, then paste.

**Code:**

Here is my code for detecting a button click and copying an image:

```
- (IBAction) clickedImage:(id)sender {
    UIButton *btn = sender;
    UIImage *scaledImage = btn.imageView.image;
    UIImage *newImage = [scaledImage imageWithImage:scaledImage andSize:CGSizeMake(75, 75)];
    NSData *imgData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);

    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    [pasteboard setData:imgData forPasteboardType:[UIPasteboardTypeListImage objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

And I have a UIImage category with the `imageWithImage:andSize:` method for scaling the image.  This is the scaling method:

```
- (UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image andSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    // Create a bitmap context.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, image.scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

What doesn't make sense is that when I put the image in the UIButton it is scaled down to the exact same size as when I scale using code, but the quality is way better for the UIButton than when I return the scaled image.  Is there something wrong with my scaling code? Does anyone know why there is such a drop in quality between the two images?

Comment: You are retrieving the image from the button. Is it the same if you create new `UIImage` from resource?

Comment: @Losiowaty yes, I've tried creating a new UIImage and it is the same

Comment: Are these images that could be better represented as vector graphics and then output at whatever scaling was required?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this https://github.com/mbcharbonneau/UIImage-Categories ?

There is an interesting method in the Resize category

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
     interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality;
```

Setting quality to `kCGInterpolationHigh` seems to give a good result (a little bit slower)

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to use `ImageIO` to resize your images. It takes a little bit longer, but it is far better for scaling images than redrawing into a graphics context.